# why mobile menu won't work on first click, but works fine on subsequent clicks?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make a mobile menu for my website using JS and css, when I first click the button it doesn't respond, but it works fine on subsequent clicks, and also there is a tiny delay on first menu drop that goes away on subsequent clicks.

what could be the reason for these?

I tried to console.log the "top" property at the beginning of the webpage but it gives empty space, then with frequent clicks gives a value of "-110%" or "60px"
**html**

```js
const mobile = window.matchMedia("max-width: 768px;");
let menu = document.querySelector(".aside");

if (mobile.matches) {
  document.querySelector(".scroll").addEventListener(onclick, toggleMenu());
}

function toggleMenu() {

  if (menu.style.top == "-110%") {
    menu.style.top = "60px";
  } else {
    menu.style.top = "-110%";
  }
}
```

```css
header {
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fcf1ee;
  z-index: 2;
}

.mobile-menu-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #5cebb5 0%, #225139 84%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: #448d76;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.aside {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 5%;
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom right, rgba(68, 141, 118, 0.9) 0%, rgba(53, 121, 86, 0.9) 76%);
  box-shadow: 10px 20px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-radius: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -110%;
  transition: 1s;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <button class="mobile-menu-button scroll" onClick="toggleMenu()"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
 </button>
</header>
<div class="aside">
  <div class="avatar-container">
    <div class="avatar"></div>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="scroll" data-value="about">
        About
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="scroll" data-value="resume">
        Resume
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#portfolio" class="scroll" data-value="portfolio">
        Portfolio
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#contact" class="scroll" data-value="contact">
        Contact
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obe is right but if you still want a solution then you can go with something like below:

```
if (menu.style.top == "-110%" || menu.style.top == "") {
   menu.style.top = "60px";
} else {
   menu.style.top = "-110%";
}
```

This will work as on 1st click top value will be "" always.

Comment: I didn't offer a solution because a solution wasn't requested, and this solution is not bad, but I would recommend to look at what @sloont suggested. His approach is cleaner, more expressive, and more maintainable in the long run (though I'd change it a bit and not rely on specific indices in `menu.classList`)

Comment: I am totally in agreement with you. @MohamadHasan a better approach for this functionality is what sloont is suggesting.

Comment: sure I will study sloont's solution, I just need more JS learning.

Answer (score 2):

This check:

```
if (menu.style.top == "-110%")
```

Literally checks for a `style` attribute on the element. Since you don't have that - it evaluates to `false` in the first click.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was missing, I thought it changed the css file.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've gotten some good answers already but I've been working on it for a minute so I'll post what I did.

I added classes so that you can use them for other styling based on the appearance of the menu.

Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-gagarin-gl31q?file=/src/styles.css);

In the html page, I just added a `<body>` around the content. In my example I also remove the `onClick` attribute from the button in the html.

In the JS, I cleaned it up and removed the `mobile` variable because you don't need it to test in browser. You can easily add it back to the script to test mobile only.

```
let button = document.getElementsByClassName("scroll")[0];
let menu = document.getElementsByClassName("aside")[0];

const toggleMenu = function () {
  console.log("button clicked");

  if (menu.classList.length === 1) {
    return menu.classList.add("active");
  }

  if (menu.classList[1] === "active") {
    return menu.classList.replace("active", "inactive");
  }

  if (menu.classList[1] === "inactive") {
    return menu.classList.replace("inactive", "active");
  }
};

button.addEventListener("click", () => toggleMenu());
```

There's definitely a way to do it with just a class for `"active"`, but it would look almost the same.

The CSS was the most important change. We add `transition` properties that apply to the `top` property.

```
.aside {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 6rem 5% 0 5%;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom right,
    rgba(68, 141, 118, 0.9) 0%,
    rgba(53, 121, 86, 0.9) 76%
  );
  box-shadow: 10px 20px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-radius: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -110%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.aside.active {
  top: 0% !important;
  transition: top 1s;
}
.aside.inactive {
  top: -110% !important;
  transition: top 1s;
}
```

when the classes `active` and `inactive` are applied to the element of class `aside` the `top` property is overriden and the `transition` property fires its function.

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thanks, I get the logic behind your code, (adding a class that does what I want with the menu) except that I'm still taking my first steps in JS so I have to learn more about the functions you used here.

Answer (score 0):

menu.style.top does not return the first time. It does not look at the css but rather at the style attribute in your html (which is not there).

A simple fix could be:

```
function toggleMenu() {
  if (menu.style.top == "60px") {
    menu.style.top = "-110%";
  } else {
    menu.style.top = "60px";
  }
}
```

And keep everything else like in your question.

Basically, with your code the first time it will change nothing because in the "else" is the current state. By rotating them around the first click will actually have the other state in there.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nf49d7me/

A simple way to debug this is to add an:

```
alert(menu.style.top);
```

in the toggleMenu function. You will see the values it's using.